# onUploadProgress only calling when whole file uploaded

Tags: reactjs, axios, fetch

I am uploading files. My requirement is to show the progress of the file upload. For this, I am using the `onUploadProgress` function, but this function is only called after the whole file is uploaded. However, it should be called as soon as the loading state of the file changes.

```
export const awsFileUploader = async ( files: FileUploadItem[], progressSetter: React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<number>>, bucketName: string ): Promise<any[]> => { const totalFiles = files.length; let uploadedFiles = 0; let uploadResults: any[] = [];
const handleUploadComplete = async () => {
    uploadedFiles++;
    const progress = Math.round((uploadedFiles / totalFiles) * 100);
    progressSetter(progress);
};

const uploadPromises = files.map((fileUploadItem) => {
    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('file', fileUploadItem.file);
    formData.append('fileName', fileUploadItem.name);
    formData.append('key', fileUploadItem.key);
    formData.append('bucketName', bucketName);

    return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
        try {
        const response = await axios.post(
            `${process.env.REACT_APP_backend_api_url}/upload-file`,
            formData,
            {
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
                    },
                onUploadProgress: (progressEvent) => {
                    console.count('=====******');
                    // const { loaded, total } = 
                       progressEvent;
                    // let percent = Math.floor((loaded * 100) / total);
                    // console.log(`${loaded} bytes of ${total} bytes. ${percent}%`);
                    },
                }
            );

            if (response.status !== 201) {
                throw new Error('Failed to upload file');
            }

            await handleUploadComplete();
            const data = response.data;
            const uploadData: FileListItem = {
                url: data.url,
                name: fileUploadItem.name,
                awsFileName: fileUploadItem.key,
                key: data.Key,
            };
            resolve(uploadData);
        } catch (error) {
            reject(error);
        }
    });
});

try {
    const uploadResults = await Promise.all(uploadPromises);
    progressSetter(100); // Set progress to 100 once all files are uploaded
    return uploadResults;
} catch (error) {
    progressSetter(0);`your text`
    throw error;
}
};
```

What should I change in my code in order to have `onUploadProgress` called the moment the loading stage changes?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I've edited your question in order to make it more readable. Please do check whether it still reflects your desired meaning. Note that whilst speaking perfect English is not a requirement on SO, at least spending minimal effort to e.g. split sentences makes it significantly easier for others to correct your posts.